# QlikView: Input Box Not Accepting Values

Tags: qlikview

I created a variable vAverageSalary and an input box which serves as a place to change the value of the variable (variable is defined as money). The problem is that nothing happens when I enter numbers in the input box for the variable. Additionaly when I check the value in the 'Variable Overview' for that varable, I see nothing. Even if I try to define here any value for the variable, nothing changes. And the third option I tried was to define any value by going to the 'Properties' of the input box and entering any value in the 'Settings for the Selected Value' (Tab - 'Constraints'). Even when I enter a value here, nothing happes - the system simply ignores everything I enter.

How can I make an input box to take the value I enter in it?

UPDATE: It seems that the problem is when I define the variable inside the input box as 'Money' - I can only set velue when I type for example '121,00 €'. However if I make a text box and try to write out the value of the variable, I get the message "Error: Garbage after expression ','". The input box takes the values in that format, but the output is garbage. And if I type for example any number without '€' sign, than input box ignores my input and gives me the previous value... Why?

Comment: When you writing the variable in a text object, are you using =$(vAverageSalary)? Try without the dollar sign:  =vAverageSalary

Comment: The problem is not with the text object but with the input box - I want to enter a value in the input box to change a variable (the variable is used later in a table). And changing a value (in this case the type is money) is not working.

Comment: What does your constraints tab on the input box look like? I tried on my side and if I set the number format to Money in the number tab I still only have to enter the numeric value and it adds the other symbols. If I type the numerics and symbols it doesn't recognize it but still puts the value there.